# How to know if the ios addressbook can access Facebook contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, abaddressbook

On iOS, I want to know if the user has enabled the contacts app to include Facebook contacts.
(He does so in the iPhone settings under "Facebook", where apps are listed that can connect with facebook).
When the Contacts app can connect with Facebook, the user has the option to check "All facebook" in Contacts, so I figured it might be simply a group. But after checking the names of all groups on a test device (where Contacts is connected with Facebook), no group named "all facebook" or similar showed up.
So I am wondering: is there any way at all to know if Contacts includes Facebook friends? I did not find anything in the documentation.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External sources in iOS are not represented as groups, they are defined as `ABSource` records.

Look for `ABSource` records where `KABSourceTypeProperty` is NOT set to `KABSourceTypeLocal`. That will pick up everything besides device-local and iCloud-synced contacts. I'm not sure how to identify which source (Facebook, Exchange etc.) a particular `ABSource` refers to.

Comment: Thanks. I have two sources listed, one of them (of type kABSourceTypeLocal) contains all my groups, the other one, (of type kABSourceTypeCardDAV) seems to contain nothing. So I guess it is not for us to know if Contacts is allowed to fetch data from Facebook :(